# Can I get sum of a list values (not occurrences of index values) in Python

Tags: python, list

I have an output list like,

```
[['0'], ['happy', 1], ['happy', 1.5], ['0'], ['sad', 1], ['0'], ['0'], ['happy', 1]]
```

So I want to get sum of the each same values. According to this list the output should be,

```
happy weight : 3.5
0 count : 4
sad weight : 1
```

I tried to find a way to do this and I still fail to find a correct way for that. Can anyone tell me can I get the output as I expected.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: What should `[['0'],['0',5]]` produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation fits your criteria, but as @ScottHunter said, there is some vagueness.

```
lst = [['0'], ['happy', 1], ['happy', 1.5], ['0'], ['sad', 1], ['0'], ['0'], ['happy', 1]]


def update_count(item_key, increase, dictionary):
    try:
        dictionary[item_key] += increase
    except KeyError:
        dictionary[item_key] = increase

item_counts = dict()
for item in lst:
    size = len(item)
    if size == 1:
        update_count(item[0], 1, item_counts)
    elif size == 2:
        update_count(item[0], item[1], item_counts)
    else:
        print("Too many elements in item!")

print(item_counts)
```

---

Or you can use `collections.Counter` if you prefer to leave out the `try/except`:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [['0'], ['happy', 1], ['happy', 1.5], ['0'], ['sad', 1], ['0'], ['0'], ['happy', 1]]

item_counts = Counter()
for item in lst:
    size = len(item)
    if size == 1:
        item_counts[item[0]] += 1
    elif size == 2:
        item_counts[item[0]] += item[1]
    else:
        print("Too many elements in item!")

print(item_counts)
```

Using [`defaultdict`](https://www.ludovf.net/blog/python-collections-defaultdict/) from `collections`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [['0'], ['happy', 1], ['happy', 1.5], ['0'], ['sad', 1], ['0'], ['0'], ['happy', 1]]

item_counts = defaultdict(int)  # the int() func returns 0 if key doesn't exist
for item in lst:
    size = len(item)
    if size == 1:
        item_counts[item[0]] += 1
    elif size == 2:
        item_counts[item[0]] += item[1]
    else:
        print("Too many elements in item!")

print(item_counts)
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I expected.

Answer (score 4):

The more static way of doing it.

```
l=[['0'], ['happy', 1], ['happy', 1.5], ['0'], ['sad', 1], ['0'], ['0'], 
['happy', 1]]
print(sum(1 for x in l if x[0]=='0'))
print(sum(x[1] for x in l if x[0]=='happy'))
print(sum(x[1] for x in l if x[0]=='sad'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [['0'], ['happy', 1], ['happy', 1.5], ['0'], ['sad', 1], ['0'], ['0'], ['happy', 1]]
d = {k: 0 for k in set([i[0] for i in x])}

for i in x:
    if len(i) == 1:
        d[i[0]] += 1
    elif len(i) == 2:
        d[i[0]] += i[1]

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

using a dict

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
l = [['0'], ['happy', 1], ['happy', 1.5], ['0'], ['sad', 1], ['0'], ['0'], ['happy', 1]]

from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for v in l:
    c[v[0]] += 1 if len(v) == 1 else v[1]

print c  # Counter({'0': 4, 'happy': 3.5, 'sad': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using an 3rd party extension, you could use [`iteration_utilities.groupedby`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/groupedby.html)<sup>1</sup>:

```
lst = [['0'], ['happy', 1], ['happy', 1.5], ['0'], ['sad', 1], ['0'], ['0'], ['happy', 1]]
from iteration_utilities import groupedby

for key, value in groupedby(lst, lambda x: x[0]).items():
    if key == '0':
        print(key, 'count:', len(value))
    else:
        print(key, 'weight:', sum(x[1] for x in value))
```

which prints:

```
0 count: 4
happy weight: 3.5
sad weight: 1
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclaimer: I'm the author of that library